# Pass v-model through a child component to another one

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I currently have a component called `generic-input`. It basically is a input, which can also take a filter function as a prop and apply it to the input. This alone is working.

I now want to create concrete sub-components, which simply pass a predefined filter function to `generic-input`. This is not working.

---

**My current layout (working example, before sub-components):**
*GenericInput.vue*

```html
<template>
  <input ref="input" :value="objectValue" @input="inputHandler(§event.target.value)" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: undefined,
    toObjectType: {
      type: Function,
      default: (x) => (x),
    },
    filter: {
      type: Function,
      default: (x) => (x),
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      objectValue: null,
      handler: true,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(val) {
        let newValue = val;
        if (newValue) {
          newValue = this.toObjectType(newValue);
          newValue = this.filter(newValue);
          if (newValue !== val) {
            this.$emit("input", newValue);
          }
        }
        this.objectValue = newValue;
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    inputHandler(val) {
      this.updateValue(this.toObjectType(val), val);
    },
    updateValue: function (val, strVal = null) {
      const oldVal = this.objectValue;
      val = this.filter(val);
      if (val === oldVal) {
        this.$refs.input.value = strVal && val === this.toObjectType(strVal) ? strVal : null;
        return;
      }
      this.objectValue = val;
      this.$emit("input", val);
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

> *Breakdown:*
> Need to use `objectValue`, otherwise I get a mutable error on `value`. But now I have to use a watcher on `value`. `inputHandler`and `updateValue` simply update the value according to the filter.

> [Inspiration](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/vue-number-input/blob/main/src/vue-number-input.vue)

**Usage**: `<generic-input v-model="myModel" />`

Again, this works perfectly.

---

**Now**, I want to create sub-components of `generic-input` such as `number-input`. Those sub-components have predefined (dynamic) `toObjectType` and `filter` methods.

**Not working minimal example:**
*NumberInput.vue*

```html
<template>
  <generic-input />
</template>
```

I know this is not working, since the parent, which has the `numeric-input`-tag does not react to changes (`v-if`) . This does not happen when using `generic-input` instead (everything works as expected then).

→ Model-Variable is not being updated.

I have experimented, how to use `number-input` then. All didn't seem to work.
Ideas:

- `v-model` on `generic-input` or `number-input`
- `.sync`

---

**I never want to change the value of my model in a sub-component of `generic-input`. I only want to pass it along the sub-component to `generic-input`.**

Comment: So, you want to pass it from a children to `generic-input` (the parent)? Can't you use an `$emit` here? I maybe understood it poorly tho (sorry). Btw, did you checked the Vue event tab to see what/who emits anything?

Comment: Yes so basically. Parent -> Sub-Component -> `generic-input`. I have read some about `$emit`, it still confuses me a bit though.

Comment: If you want to pass some props from parent to child, you do use `props` like `:value="objectValue"` as you did. If you want the data to go from child to parent, you need to use `$emit` in the child. Let's say that you do have a child named `child.vue` and that there is an `$emit('updated', value)`, then you need to listen to it in the parent with `<child @updated="reactToUpdate"></child>`. Then, you could call the `reactToUpdate` method and access to the variable passed from the child inside of the parent. If you have a 3 level depth as told in previous comment, you have to do this twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@kissu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8816585/kissu) mentioned in a comment, simply use `$emit`. As I always emit an `input`-event in *GenericInput.vue* on a change anyway, I can simply add a few lines to my sub-component files.

A minimal working example would be:
*NumberInput.vue*

```
<template>
  <generic-input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event)" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: Number,
  },
}
</script>
```

Along with the `generic-input` as written in the question, you can use the sub-component `number-input` (in my case) with:

```
<number-input v-model="model" />
```

---

*Thank you for the help!*